# Upload database information with INSERT INTO

Tags: php, database, mysqli, insert-into

this is my image upload code, it works fine but i have a problem putting the path in my database with the function "INSERT INTO", it doesn't work.
My image goes to the folder but the column 'Image' of the table 'pages' in my database is blank, no path uploaded.
Any advice?

```
<?php
# FileName="Connection_php_mysql.htm"
# Type="MYSQL"
# HTTP="true"
$hostname_localhost = "localhost";
$database_localhost = "database";
$username_localhost = "root";
$password_localhost = "";
$localhost = new mysqli($hostname_localhost, $username_localhost, $password_localhost);

if ($localhost->connect_error) {
  die('Connect Error (' . $localhost->connect_errno . ') '. $localhost->connect_error);
} 
?>
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['UploadFileField'])){

    // Creates the Variables needed to upload the file

    $UploadName = $_FILES['UploadFileField']['name'];
    $UploadName = mt_rand(100000, 999999).$UploadName;
    $UploadTmp = $_FILES['UploadFileField']['tmp_name'];
    $UploadType = $_FILES['UploadFileField']['type'];
    $FileSize = $_FILES['UploadFileField']['size'];

    // Removes Unwanted Spaces and characters from the files names of the files being uploaded

    $UploadName = preg_replace("#[^a-z0-9.]#i", "", $UploadName);

    // Upload File Size Limit 

    if(($FileSize > 250000)){

        die("Error - File to Big");

    }

    // Checks a File has been Selected and Uploads them into a Directory on your Server

    if(!$UploadTmp){
        die("No File Selected, Please Upload Again");
    }else{
        $move=move_uploaded_file($UploadTmp, 'images/'.$UploadName);

        mysqli_query($localhost,"INSERT INTO pages (Image) 
VALUES (/pages/images/.$UploadName)");

mysqli_close($localhost);

    }
    if($move) {

   echo("file ".$UploadName." has been uploaded!");
   echo("<br>/pages/images/".$UploadName);
    }else {
        exit("unable to upload the file" .$UploadName);
        }
        }

?>
```

Thank you!

Comment: You need to put the string in single quotes `INSERT INTO pages (Image) 
VALUES ('/pages/images/$UploadName')`.

Comment: Doesn't work, must be something else :-\

Comment: Check for mysql errors http://php.net/mysqli_error

Comment: Error: no database selected... but i set up it in the $localhost...

Comment: But you're not giving it to the `mysqli` constructor. Should be `mysqli($hostname_localhost, $username_localhost, $password_localhost, $database_localhost);`

Comment: Ok solved, forgot the database spec in the $localhost!